# Firebase error when trying to create an account

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication

I wrote a function for creating accounts in Firebase two months ago and it worked, now when I try to create an account it gives me the next error message:

> I/BiChannelGoogleApi(19700): [FirebaseAuth: ] getGoogleApiForMethod() returned Gms: com.google.firebase.auth.api.internal.zzaq@94e857b

The function that I created for doing that stuff is the next one:

```
 Future<void> register() async {
final formState = _formKey.currentState;
if (formState.validate()) {
  formState.save();
  print('$_email si $_password');
  try {
    FirebaseUser user = (await FirebaseAuth.instance
            .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
                email: _email.trim(), password: _password,  ))
        .user;


     user.sendEmailVerification();
     presentError("Now you own an account", context);
      await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 1));
          Navigator.pushReplacement(
              context,
              MaterialPageRoute(
                  builder: (context) => LoginPageState(title: 'LoginPage')));
  } catch (e) {
    print(e);}
```

Comment: That's not an error.  The "I" at the start of the line indicates it's just information.

Comment: But the code doesn't work, it just shows me that line.

Comment: There is probably another log there somewhere. Could you give us more information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you don't have updated your FirebaseAuth Rules and the unsafe period is over.
See https://firebase.google.com/docs/rules/rules-and-auth

Comment: The login works, only thing that doesn't work is creating accounts.